# Конструктор FormData не забирает данные из форvs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, formdata

Не ругайте за банальный вопрос, но ответа не нашел.
Хочу забрать данные из формы, чтобы потом объект конвертировать в json и отправить через ajax.
но при попытке вывести json через alert или console.log выводится пустая строка.
В чем моя ошибка?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  id="myform" name="myform" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="first" value="first"></br>
      <input type="text" name="second" value="second"></br>
      <input id="send" type="button" name="submit" value="send">
    </form>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
let data = new FormData(document.getElementById('myform'));
let json = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(json);
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: "В чем моя ошибка?" - в использовании `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: а какой способ тогда лучше использовать?

Comment: попробовал посмотреть, что в объекте через console.log(data.name).
выдает undefined

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что там есть свойство `name`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: попробовал сделать через JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeArray()), начал выдавать строку
вот результат из консоли "[{\"name\":\"first\",\"value\":\"first\"},{\"name\":\"second\",\"value\":\"second\"}]"

Comment: При чем здесь `FormData`?

Comment: если я правильно понял, то нужно использовать FormData.keys() и в цикле перегнать данные в другой объект. Или есть еще варианты?

Comment: Как Вы отправляете ajax-запрос?

Comment: я пока еще до этого не дошел
но мне нужно отправить его методом post, в формате json

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = new FormData(document.getElementById('myform'));
let jsonObject = {};
data.forEach((value, key) => {jsonObject[key] = value});
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]